# Simplify replacing vector elements according to criteria using an apply function

Tags: r

I've got a dataset that has a variable called `Region` that represents different areas within Australia. Here are 25 rows from the data:

```
> head(sample.2013$Region, n = 25)
 [1] QLD major urban - capital city   VIC rural                        NSW regional - low urbanisation 
 [4] SA regional - low urbanisation   NSW regional - low urbanisation  Tas rural                       
 [7] ACT major urban - capital city   QLD rural                        ACT major urban - capital city  
[10] NT regional - low urbanisation   NSW other                        QLD rural                       
[13] ACT major urban - capital city   VIC regional - high urbanisation Tas rural                       
[16] QLD major urban - capital city   Tas rural                        VIC regional - high urbanisation
[19] QLD rural                        Tas rural                        VIC rural                       
[22] QLD other urban                  Tas rural                        VIC rural                       
[25] ACT major urban - capital city
36 Levels: ACT major urban - capital city NSW major urban - capital city NSW other urban ... ?
```

#### Naive Solution

I need to make another variable called `state` based off the variables within this column. Currently I'm just using a brute force method to create a new vector like this:

```
add_states <- function(sample.2013) {
    # Add states from the region variable
    sample.2013$State[grepl('NSW', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'NSW'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('VIC', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'VIC'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('QLD', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'QLD'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('WA', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'WA'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('SA', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'SA'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('Tas', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'TAS'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('TAS', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'TAS'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('ACT', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'ACT'
    sample.2013$State[grepl('NT', sample.2013$Region) == TRUE] <- 'NT'
    return(sample.2013)
}
```

This works fine, but it's difficult to test and is brittle. For example I now know that I can just pass `ignore-case` to `grepl`, which would remove the need for the two Tasmanian cases.

#### For loops

I've been able to replace the above 'naive' approach with a for loop and a function like this:

```
add_state <- function(input, output, state) {
    # Change the variable y in place, prevents duplication
    output <- replace(output, grepl(state, input, ignore.case = TRUE), state)
    output
}

state_codes <- c('NSW', 'VIC', 'QLD', 'WA', 'SA', 'TAS', 'ACT', 'NT')
test_vector <- head(sample.2013$Region, n = 500)

y = vector('character', length = length(test_vector))

for (i in 1:length(state_codes)) {
    y <- add_state(test_vector, y, state_codes[i])
}

    table(y)
y
    ACT NSW  NT QLD  SA TAS VIC  WA 
 14  99  50  42  49  98  92  45  11
```

But this is also quite verbose and for loops are not idiomatic R. I haven't been able to replace this code with an apply function and get it to replace values in a vector, rather than create a bunch of other vectors.

#### Lapply

This is the best I've managed using `lapply`:

```
add_state3 <- function(x, state) {
    x <- replace(x, grepl(state, x, ignore.case = TRUE), state)
    x
}

test_vector_short <- c("NSW 1", "NSW 2", "Vic", "Goo")

> output <- lapply(state_codes, add_state3, x = test_vector_short)
> output
[[1]]
[1] "NSW" "NSW" "Vic" "Goo"

[[2]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "VIC"   "Goo"  

[[3]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "Vic"   "Goo"  

[[4]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "Vic"   "Goo"  

[[5]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "Vic"   "Goo"  

[[6]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "Vic"   "Goo"  

[[7]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "Vic"   "Goo"  

[[8]]
[1] "NSW 1" "NSW 2" "Vic"   "Goo"
```

The function works, it takes each instance of state code and passes that to the add_state3 function, but it creates a list with 8 elements, rather than replacing the elements in place.

#### Question

Sorry about the long preamble, but essentially my question is how do I use an apply function to change elements of a vector *in place* according to some criteria?

Comment: Minor point: You don't need the `== TRUE` in `grepl(...) == TRUE`, because `grepl()` already returns a logical vector (as the test itself indicates).

Comment: @bgoldst yeah I noticed that after posting. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `gsub` to combine your search and replace, e.g. `gsub('^.*\\bNT\\b.*$', 'NT')` will replace all matching NT strings (the `\\b` to avoid things like "pint" matching "NT").

If you make your regex something like `'^.*\\b(NSW|NT|QLD|...)\b.*'`, and then you replace with `\\1` (the captured match), you can do:

```
state.regex <- sprintf('^.*\\b(%s)\\b.*$', paste(state_codes, collapse='|'))
# "^.*\\b(NSW|VIC|QLD|WA|SA|TAS|ACT|NT)\\b.*$"
gsub(state.regex, '\\1', test_vector_short, ignore.case=T)
# [1] "NSW" "NSW" "Vic" "Goo"
```

This just hinges on the fact that whenever you find a match you want to replace the entire with the match, and that the matches (state codes) can be condensed into one regex.

Otherwise, I believe you have to loop as you have done (since you need to do your replacements, then replace on the updated vector).

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a pattern of `STATECODE other stuff` so you could just `strsplit` and take the first element

Using `test`:

```
test <- c(
  "QLD major urban - capital city",
  "Vic rural",
  "NSW regional - low urbanisation", 
  "SA regional - low urbanisation",
  "NSW regional - low urbanisation",
  "guff and goo"
)

result <- toupper(sapply(strsplit(test," "),`[`,1))
replace(result, !result %in% state_codes, NA)
#[1] "QLD" "VIC" "NSW" "SA"  "NSW" NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the first word of each `Region` is the state code, you can just strip off the rest and use the result as the new `state` variable:

```
sample.2013 <- data.frame(Region=c('QLD major urban - capital city','VIC rural','NSW regional - low urbanisation','SA regional - low urbanisation','NSW regional - low urbanisation  Tas rural','ACT major urban - capital city','QLD rural','ACT major urban - capital city','NT regional - low urbanisation','NSW other','QLD rural','ACT major urban - capital city','VIC regional - high urbanisation Tas rural','QLD major urban - capital city','Tas rural','VIC regional - high urbanisation','QLD rural','Tas rural','VIC rural','QLD other urban','Tas rural','VIC rural','ACT major urban - capital city'));
sample.2013$state <- toupper(sub(' .*','',sample.2013$Region));
sample.2013;
##                                        Region state
## 1              QLD major urban - capital city   QLD
## 2                                   VIC rural   VIC
## 3             NSW regional - low urbanisation   NSW
## 4              SA regional - low urbanisation    SA
## 5  NSW regional - low urbanisation  Tas rural   NSW
## 6              ACT major urban - capital city   ACT
## 7                                   QLD rural   QLD
## 8              ACT major urban - capital city   ACT
## 9              NT regional - low urbanisation    NT
## 10                                  NSW other   NSW
## 11                                  QLD rural   QLD
## 12             ACT major urban - capital city   ACT
## 13 VIC regional - high urbanisation Tas rural   VIC
## 14             QLD major urban - capital city   QLD
## 15                                  Tas rural   TAS
## 16           VIC regional - high urbanisation   VIC
## 17                                  QLD rural   QLD
## 18                                  Tas rural   TAS
## 19                                  VIC rural   VIC
## 20                            QLD other urban   QLD
## 21                                  Tas rural   TAS
## 22                                  VIC rural   VIC
## 23             ACT major urban - capital city   ACT
```